# Como realizar multiplicação de moeda no formato brasileiro em js?

Tags: javascript

Atualmente eu possuo o seguinte formato monetário:

```
2.222,57
```

Porém quando eu dou um console.log() eu vejo que ele está como uma string:

```
console.log(this.produtos[i].price)
console.log(typeof (this.produtos[i].price))
```

Se eu tentar converter esse número pra realizar a operação, ele retorna `NaN`:

```
console.log(Number(this.produtos[i].price))
```

Se eu tento com parseFloat(this.produtos[i].price), eu obtenho:
2.222 porém eu perco o valor das últimas duas casas decimais e quando eu realizo multplicações, por exemplo:

```
let valor = parseFloat(this.produtos[i].price * 5)
```

Eu recebo: `11.11`.

Como eu posso realizar operações matemáticas em javascript com o formato monetario brasileiro?
Se isso não for possível, como eu posso converter o `11.11` para o respectivo resultado `11.112,85` ?

Comment: Remove todos os caracteres não numéricos da string para então realizar o cálculo, depois divide por 10 e coloca os pontos e vínrgula de volta

Comment: Fiz dessa forma, porém eu perco o valor das duas casas decimais quando passo para float:


et valor = this.produtos[i].price
        valor.replace('.', '')
        valor.replace(',', '')
        valor = parseFloat(valor)
        valor = valor * this.produtos[i].quantidade

Comment: Operação matemática não guarda relação nenhuma com formato monetário (internamente números não tem formatação). Formato monetário só deve ser aplicado na fase de exibição. Tem que consertar a origem do dado. Com o que foi postado na pergunta vai ser um show de gambiarras na área de respostas.

Comment: @veroneseComS por isso tu divide por **100** ao final do cálculo (não por 10, errei no comentário anterior), faz o cálculo como inteiro depois volta pra decimal

Comment: @Bacco meu frontend me traz os valores com pontos e virgulas, mas acredito que já deu uma clareada

Comment: números não sinal de milhares, e o separador de decimais é o ponto, não vírgula. Use `replace` pare resolver isso antes de converter para `float`

Comment: @veroneseComS idealmente seria bom já converter em numérico assim que capturar o dado. Preferencialmente o front já mandar certo, se usar ajax (até para poder corrigir o locale, caso o front seja internacionalizável)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como foi dito nos comentários a melhor forma trabalhar com moeda no comércio é removendo caracteres não numéricos(pontos de agrupamento e virgula decimal) operacionalizar e reajustar o resultado dividindo por 100.

O resultado dessas operações resulta num objeto [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) que não possui símbolos de agrupamento de milhar e o separador decimal é o ponto. O que faz necessário formatar esse resultado para suas nescessidades.

Para obter a formatação culturalmente específica deve-se usar o método [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) retorna uma string com uma representação sensível a determinada cultura para esse número.

O primeiro argumento de `toLocaleString()` é `local` que informa a cultura em que será formatado o número. O valor para esse local é uma string no formato [`BCP 74/RFC 5646`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646) os valores válidos para `local` estão listados em http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry. Aqui eu usei como local `pt-BR`.

O segundo argumento é um objeto `opção` que são as opções de formatação, funcionam como um ajuste mais refinado.

Para o seu caso eu criei dois exemplos de formatação.

Um formatando diretamente em moeda corrente o que inclui o simbolo monetário para Reais(R$) que pode ser especificado no objeto `opções` setando as propriedades `style: 'currency'` para indicar a formatação em moeda local e `currency: 'BRL'` para indicar o simbolo monetário a ser inserido no caso `BRL` que significa Real Brasileiro. Aqui tem uma lista de com os valores para símbolos monetários: [ISO 4217 Current currency & funds code list](https://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html).

O outro exemplo formatando como um número decimal, que acho o mais adequado a sua pergunta. Setei as propriedades do objeto `opções` em `style: 'decimal'` para indicar a formatação em um número decimal, `useGrouping: 'true'`(valor default, não precisaria ser usado) para exibir o caractere(.) agrupador de milhar, `minimumFractionDigits: '2'` para exibir um mínimo de duas casas decimais e maximumFractionDigits: '2'(valor default, não precisaria ser usado) para restringir a formatação ao máximo em duas casas decimais.

```js
//Não sabia do se tratava o seu estoque, criei um fictício.
const produtos = [{
    'name': 'perucas fio de prata',
    'price': '2.222,57'
  },
  {
    'name': 'perucas fio de ouro',
    'price': '5.000.326,90'
  },
  {
    'name': 'perucas fio de barbante',
    'price': '1.326,00'
  }
];



produtos.forEach((currentValue) => {
  // Remoção do caracteres não numéricos.
  let rawPrice = parseInt(currentValue.price.replace(/[.,]/g, ''));
  let quantity = parseInt(prompt(`Deseja comprar quantas ${currentValue.name} ?`));
  // Operacionalização e reajuste do resultado.
  let total = (rawPrice * quantity / 100);

  //Caso queira o valor formatado como moeda(incluio simbolo ISO 4217 para moeda).
  alert(`${currentValue.name}(resultado em moeda): ${quantity} X ${currentValue.price} = ${total.toLocaleString('pt-BR',{ style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })}`);

  //Caso queira o valor formatdo apenas como decimal com duas casas.
  alert(`${currentValue.name}(resultado em decimal): ${quantity} X ${currentValue.price} = ${total.toLocaleString('pt-BR',{ style: 'decimal', useGrouping: 'true', minimumFractionDigits: '2', maximumFractionDigits: '2' })}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode criar um função que remove os pontos e as virgulas e trabalhar com o valor em centavos.

```
var currency = "100.100,10";
function onlyNumber(str) {
        if (str){
            if (typeof str === "number") {
                str = str.toString()
                return parseInt(str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""))
            }
            return str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
        }
    }
```

parseInt(onlyNumber(currency));

Answer (score 0):

seguindo o que você mandou eu faria operações matemáticas com esse número dessa forma :

```
const produtos = ['2.222,57'];

let numero = produtos[0].replace(/[.]+/g, '');
numero = numero.replace(/[,]+/g, '.');
const valor = Number(numero);
console.log(valor * 5);
```

isso é um caso que aconteceu comigo ao usar um *Input* que formatava o valor para o formato monetário brasileiro. 
Espero ter ajudado (^-^)

Answer (score -1):

```
export function currency(value: string): string {
  if (!value) return value;

  const number_value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');

  const get_value = ((Number(number_value) / 100).toFixed(2) + '').split('.');

  const format_value = get_value[0]
    .split('')
    .reverse()
    .join('')
    .match(/.{1,3}/g);

  if (!format_value) return value;

  for (let i = 0; i < format_value.length; i++)
    format_value[i] = format_value[i].split('').reverse().join('') + '.';

  const r = format_value.reverse().join('');

  const new_value = r.substring(0, r.lastIndexOf('.')) + ',' + get_value[1];

  return `R$ ${new_value}`;
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).